# Circle pulsation increments

Tags: javascript

I have working code below that creates a circle in a canvas over an image areas and with pulsating animation.My problem is if I click twice the Red circle, it will pulsate faster and if click again it will pulsate again very fast.How will change the code so the pace of pulsation is consistent.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>HTML5 input </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <style>
    canvas
    {
        pointer-events: none;   /* make the canvas transparent to the mouse - needed since canvas is position infront of image */
        position: absolute; 
    }

    area{
    position: absolute;
    border:none;
    }

     </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <body id="myBodyId" >

       <canvas id='canvas'></canvas> 
       <center>
        <div id="myDiv1">

        <img src="https://s12.postimg.org/sflskn1y5/shapes.jpg" id="pinch-zoom-image-id" usemap="#image-map"/>

        </div>
        <map name="image-map">

                <area shape="circle" onclick="getid(this.coords)" coords="101,81,36" href="#">
                <area shape="circle" onclick="getid(this.coords)" coords="148,81,12" nohref >
                <area shape="circle" onclick="getid(this.coords)" coords="100,81,59" href="#">

         </center>
    </body>    
    </html>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Script

```
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
window.onload = function(){
    }

    var hdc;
    var angle = 0;
    var coord;

    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                window.msRequestAnimationFrame;                                     

    function getid(coordStr){

             coord = coordStr.split(',');
             myHover();             
    }

    var ringRadius = 0;
    var ringCounter = 0;

    function myHover()
    {

        var img = byId('pinch-zoom-image-id');

        var x,y, w,h;

        // get it's position and width+height
        x = img.offsetLeft;
        y = img.offsetTop;
        w = img.clientWidth;
        h = img.clientHeight;

        // move the canvas, so it's contained by the same parent as the image
            var imgParent = img.parentNode;
            var can = byId('canvas');
            imgParent.appendChild(can);

            // place the canvas in front of the image
            can.style.zIndex = 1;

            // position it over the image
            can.style.left = x+'px';
            can.style.top = y+'px';

            // make same size as the image
            can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
            can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

            // get it's context
            hdc = can.getContext('2d');

        // set the 'default' values for the colour/width of fill/stroke operations
            hdc.fillStyle = 'red';
            hdc.strokeStyle = 'red';
            hdc.lineWidth = 4;

            var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
            hdc = can.getContext('2d');

            var canvasWidth = can.width;
            var canvasHeight = can.height;
             hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                 // color in the background
                hdc.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
                //hdc.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasWidth);
                hdc.beginPath();

                var radius = 5 + 50 * Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
                hdc.arc(coord[0], coord[1], radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                hdc.closePath();
                //console.log("radius"+radius);

                hdc.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                hdc.stroke();
                angle += Math.PI / 84;

                requestAnimationFrame(myHover);

        }
```

Comment: you can disable the button when user click for first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you call the recursive function `myHover` each time you click on the circle. I would suggest storing if the circle is pulsating and not call `myHover` again if it is:

```
var pulsating = false
window.getid = function(coordStr) {
    coord = coordStr.split(',');
    if (!pulsating) {
        pulsating = true
        myHover();
    }
}
```

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/fbooygo4/